# Error during PowerShell: Input is not a valid Base 64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm getting error during PowerShell "get-Mguser" command:

```
Input is not a valid Base 64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding
```

Found a similar error link [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-graph/sdk-command-error-quot-the-input-is-not-a-valid-base-64-string/m-p/3543574) However, looks like The problem is still open. Could anyone please guide, how to fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: can you please share the query sample which you are using?

Comment: I just did "get-Mguser" and shows error,

Comment: I am not able to repo this issue from my end, just for the query "get-Mguse", can you please any modules are missing.

Comment: I updated to PowerShell MS graph module version to 1.11. Still the same issue. Any idea, what am I missing?